# Help me find the magical padding

Tags: css, flash, stylesheet, padding

There is a top padding between the flash at the top and the top corner in this page that I am designing: http://milabalami.com

I have checked my stylesheet and looked everywhere. I cannot find why there is a padding there. Is there anyone that could help me solve this bizarre puzzle?

Comment: You're definitely going to have to give us more information than that. Which browser are you testing in, exactly which code is giving you trouble, what have you tried so far? Your page on its own doesn't give us much to work on :)

Comment: I thought the title said "pudding"

Comment: @Kyle Yes, it does. The page is the demo here. I can see the issue in Chrome and based on that, I figured out what the source of the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the blackbox DIV:

```
<div id="blackbox"></div>
```

It appears before the flash DIV in the HTML source code. It has `position:relative` and is pushed down with `top:275px`. But still, it takes up space in it's original location, which is that stripe of white space on top of the page.

If you change the positioning of the blackbox DIV to - for instance - `position:absolute`, you will see that the flash DIV jumps to the top of the page.

Comment: Excellent, thats the one that I was looking for. Cheers buddy.